# Neo4j database not persisting using Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm starting a project using Neo4j and Spring Data Neo4j.  I want my program to use a local database that already contains my data (as opposed to loading the data each time on startup) since I have a lot of data that needs to be loaded into the database.  I've tried setting up a test case that populates a database with my data in order to accomplish this goal.  However, the data in the database does not appear to persist after my tests have finished running:  I look at the database using the neo4j console/shell and find it is empty.

I've constructed a small example project that's also not working.  Any insight into what I'm doing incorrectly would be appreciated.

Node entity class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Entity {
    @GraphId private Long graphId;
    private String name;
    public Entity() { }
    public Entity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends GraphRepository<Entity> { }
```

My test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class DatabaseTest {
    @Autowired Neo4jTemplate template;
    @Autowired EntityRepository entityRepository;
    @Test
    public void testCreatingEntities() {
        Entity entity1 = new Entity("one");
        Entity entity2 = new Entity("two");
        template.save(entity1);
        template.save(entity2);
        Iterator<Entity> entityIterator = entityRepository.findAll().iterator();
        List<Entity> entityList = IteratorUtils.toList(entityIterator);
        System.out.println("Number of entities = " + entityList.size());
        for(Entity entity : entityList) {
            System.out.println("Entity " + entity.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="personal.neo4j">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/test.db"
        base-package="personal.neo4j"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="personal.neo4j"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Test output:

> Running personal.neo4j.DatabaseTest 
>   Number of entities = 2 
>   Entity one 
>   Entity two

Using libraries: 
Java 1.7 
Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE 
Neo4j 2.0.2 
Spring Data Neo4j 3.0.2.RELEASE 
JUnit 4.11

Thanks for your help,

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this thread helps:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/53804-commit-transactions-running-springjunit4classrunner

Looks like SpringJUnit4ClassRunner will rollback all transactions, unless explicitly told otherwise.